# Best way to include custom react components between strings/p-tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

tldr: New to frontend. Trying to include custom components within p-tags for a website, I've tried various methods but can't seem to get it to work unless I hard code the content into the return bit in my react component - this isn't viable as I would like to have many p-tags which would change on my website when a user presses next.

Hi everyone! I'm new to front end programming, and this is my very first question, so please excuse any incorrect terminology and/or question formatting!

I'm currently working on a react project where I have created custom components to include in my webpage. These components work when placed between p-tags.

For example, I made a custom component  and it works as expected when I do something like:

```
function test{
return(
<p>Hello! This is a <ShowDefinition word="website"/> which I made using react! </p>
)}
```

However, I intend to have lots of content which would change using an incremental index, so I've placed my content in a separate jsx file to store as a dictionary.

I found that when doing something like this:

```
function test{
    return(
    <div>{script[index].content}</div>
    )};

where 
script[index].content = '<p>Hello! This is a <ShowDefinition word="website"/> which I made using react! </p>';
```

it just shows up as a string literal on the webpage. I've tried to wrap my string in {} but this did not seem to work.

I've also tried dangerouslySetInnerHTML with a dompurification to sanitise the html code

```
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: DOMPurify.sanitize(script[index].content)}};
```

This worked however it excluded all of my custom components. So for the example sentence it would show up on the page as "Hello! This is a which I made using react!"

I understand now this doesn't work because dangerouslySetInnerHTML cannot convert custom components/only accepts html, however I am now at a complete lost as to what to do.

I have thought of storing the content in a md file then parsing it however I have little knowledge of md files/md parsers and from what I've found I don't think solves my problem?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first of all, this is definitely not how you should think when playing with React. Even if this is technically possible with things like `React.createElement` or `dangerouslySetInnerHTML,` I suggest you look at [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) first. I will help you get the thinking in react.

However if I had to do this in React, I would probably use a custom hooks or any conditional logic to render my jsx.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-villani-1zdzs?file=/src/App.js:0-448)

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";

const useContentFromIndex = (index) => {
  return () => {
    if (index === 0) return <p> Index 0 </p>;
    if (index === 1) return <p> Index 1 </p>;
    return <p> Index 2 </p>;
  };
};

export default function App({ index = 0 }) {
  const CustomContent = useContentFromIndex(index);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <CustomContent />
    </div>
  );
}
```